# Plotting 3D cubicle graph using a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

Let's say we have a df consisting of 1000 rows. It contains the following 3 columns with unique values (discrete, and randomly spread through the 1000 rows) provided in the arrays:

```
X = [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9]
Y = [1, 25, 50, 75, 100]
Z = [ 0.01, 0.1, 1.0, 10.0]
```

We have identified the regions within the df such that:

```
df[(df['X'] > 0.2) & (df['X'] <= 0.7)]
df[(df['Y'] > 24) & (df['Y'] <= 80)]
df[(df['Z'] > 0.1) & (df['Z'] <= 1.0)]
```

I want to visualize this region within the data frame as a 3D graph. E.g. something where the whole df is represented a transparent(ish) cube and the identified region as a dark cube within that cube (or any other shape the region takes)

- Note that the 3 different axis are of different size but I need to visualize them as if they had same consistency.

Comment: Nice task. What have you tried, why did it fail? Probably a scatter plot with different colors and alpha values is a way to approach this.

Comment: I am looking for a code implementation for this idea

Comment: Good luck finding someone who will write you the code for free.